# Recieve SMS+email+any other way notifications through button click on website made in php

Tags: php, web, notifications, sms, gateway

I've recently made a food ecommerce based website in PHP. I've included online ordering and I'll be manually attending to orders instantly. So I need to receive a notification on one or more mobiles/emails/any other way so that one of us can instantly confirm and deliver the order. How should I go about it? What gateways are present for this kind of job? I'm willing to shell out a certain amount of money for such a service.

Thanks!!

Comment: At the very least specify what countries you intend to be operating in?

Comment: Just India For now :) But I thought most of such web services would be ubiquitous? Also, how is Ozeki sms? Anyone have any idea how much load it can handle?

Comment: SMS services like this are usually specific to a country.  I unfortunately do not have any experience within India. However, the email is something you can do by yourself without the need for an external service. PHP can be used to send emails, and if you have a smartphone with a dataplan you can set it up to have the emails pushed to your phone within seconds of them being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this service 
http://html.mobily.ws/English/Solutions/Developers/PHPSMS.html

Example included.. It will cost you 15$ for 500 SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few paid SMS APIs:

- [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com)
- [Twilio](http://twilio.com)
- [Tropo](http://tropo.com)

Pricing for all is from 1 cent to 2 cents per message. Nexmo (as far as I know), is the only SMS provider to publish quality of delivery rates, so you can see how well messages are delivered to the specific networks you'll be using (DLR rate is the important rate).

Here are a few paid email APIs:

- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/)
- [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com/)
- [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/)

All three allow both sending and * receiving* email through the API (similar to how the above SMS APIs work), meaning you could easily support email and SMS side by side. Also, parsing incoming email is painful to do manually, so if you're considering allowing a reply to take some action on the order, that will make it easy.

Pricing for all varies, but it's pretty inexpensive across the board.

*Disclaimer, I do developer evangelism part time at Nexmo.*